# Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/unpr?p0=%24scopeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope%20%3C-%20

Tags: angularjs

I'm a new in Angularjs and developing a simple Calculator application with backend support.
Since I separate controller to controller+service - there is an error like:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/unpr?p0=%24scopeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope%20%3C-%20calcService

So can anyone shed light where I'm wrong ?

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-3.0.3-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="angular/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/services/calcService.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/calcCtrl.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/resultsCtrl.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container" ng-app="app">
          <header ng-include="'templates/nav.html'"></header>
          <div ui-view></div>
          <footer ng-include="'templates/footer.html'"></footer>
        </div>    
    </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
angular
  .module('app', [
    'ui.router'
  ])
  .config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
      .state('calc', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: '../templates/calc.html',
        controller: 'calcCtrl'
      })
      .state('results', {
        url: '/results',
        templateUrl: '../templates/results.html',
        controller: 'resultsCtrl'
      })
  }]);
```

calcCtrl.js:

```
angular
  .module('app')
  //.controller('calcCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  .controller('calcCtrl', ['$scope', 'calcService', function($scope, calcService) {
    $scope.title = "Calculator";
    $scope.items = ['calc','results'];
    $scope.selectedValue = 'calc';
  }]);
```

calcService.js:

```
//angular.module('app', []);
angular.module('app')
.factory('calcService', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.calculate = function() {
        // use $.param jQuery function to serialize data from JSON 
        var data = $.param({
            left: $scope.left,
            right: $scope.right,
            operation: $scope.operation
        });

        var config = {
            headers : {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
            }
        }

        $http.post('/calc/calculate', data, config)
        .success(function (data, status) {
            $scope.responseData = "Result is : " + data;
        })
        .error(function (data, status) {
            $scope.responseData = "Data: " + data +
                "<hr />status: " + status;
        });
    };
} ]);
```

Files structure: https://gyazo.com/5d571f2a92757a4c20239cb67d8b0d5c

Here is what I'm currently have with errors in firebug: https://gyazo.com/4e367b3644b0f106938f272e2980f074
If I uncomment 1st line in calcService.js - here is a result (totally hidden UI): https://gyazo.com/fb6714f5d131ab31ae0ca17509b19968

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't inject `$scope` into a factory - how would it know what scope to inject? If you need to use scope data then you pass it from your controller as parameters on the factory methods. Also, your service should return the promise which you then handle in your controller.

Factory:

```
angular.module('app')
.factory('calcService', ['$http', function($http) {
    var service = {};
    service.calculate = function(left, right, operation) {
        // use $.param jQuery function to serialize data from JSON 
        var data = $.param({
            left: left,
            right: right,
            operation: operation
        });

        var config = {
            headers : {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
            }
        }

        return $http.post('/calc/calculate', data, config);
    };
    return service;
}]);
```

In your controller:

```
angular.module('app')
    .controller('calcCtrl', ['$scope', 'calcService', function($scope, calcService) {
        $scope.title = "Calculator";
        $scope.items = ['calc','results'];
        $scope.selectedValue = 'calc';
        $scope.calculate = function(){
            calcService.calculate($scope.left, $scope.right, $scope.operation).then(
                function(response) {
                    $scope.responseData = "Data: " + response.data;
                },
                function(error) {
                    // examine the error properties and do whatever
                }
            );
        };
    }]);
```